# Rav Elchonon Wasserman's parable on living without bread and air

Tags: sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, zionism

In Kovetz Maamarim [(p. 130, sv. "Eretz Yisrael")](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/6432/p/120/t/0.19194015243475571234/fs/CAPRK3Ebpo2rKwEt31UBbFrwFZ07RS8HKPc6wSTqUNkC/start/0/end/26/c), Rav Elchonon Wasserman zt"l explains the need to "breath the air of Torah". He says that for two thousand years, we endured many trials, many hardships, but we survived. Why? Because of Torah.

He then goes on to explain, according to a parable he gives:

> For a human being, the ability to live is given through breathing air. Without air, a person could not live. Air is needed for breathing, bread is needed to feed his heart

He then says that "what if a person lacks both? If a person lacks both air and bread.".

I was reading onward, and I understand this explanation he gives to mean that without "air"- e.g. Torah, we cannot live, but also without bread we cannot live, e.g. Eretz Yisrael. In this generation (I think Rav Wasserman refers to the Zionist-movement), people came to Eretz Yisrael, but without "air", e.g. Torah [(refer also to sefer Ir haKodesh veHamidkash, p. 10 by Rabbi    Yehiel Michel Tektzkinski).](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9433&st=&pgnum=36)

The Kovetz Maamarim reads:

> אלפתם שנה אנו קיימים בחוץ לאוץ אמנם בתנאים קשים ומדים אבל למרות הכל לא תמנו ולא כלינו גם בלעדי ארץ ישראל מתעוררת השאלה אם נתאר לעצמנו כי היהודים נשארו בלי תורה האם היו מתקיימים אלפיים שנה או לא ברור כי אפילו מאה שנה לא יוכל ישראל להתקיים בלעדי תורתו עובדא איומה נצבת לנגד עינינו במדינה האדומה זה עשרים שנה משהחלו היבסקים עוכרי ישראל לעקור את זכר התורה שם באמצעות גזירות נמחק זכר היהודי מהמדינה הזאת רק בני הדור הקודם בבחינת יהודי הדור הצעיר אין לו מושג גם קלוים היהודי נוכחנו לדעת כי בלעדי התורה אין בכוחנו להתקיים אפילו עשרות שנים ובלעדי ארץ ישראל התקיימנו משל צ לקיום האדם דרוש אויר לנשימה ולתם לעשות בשעה שהאדם חסר את שניהם ומה יש אויר או לחם ברור כי בלי אויר לא יהי' את מי להאכיל להם ארץ ישראל דרושה לעם היהודי ועוד טרם זכה לה התורה דרושה לישראל ואנו עדים לחזיון גסיסת התורה' משום שרוב הדור הצעיר מנותק ממנה נשאלת אם כן אותה השאלה למה יש לדאוג קודם כל שמד וכבר נשארו עוד ביותר על מתש שנה נמשול לסעוד את לבו מה להאפיק לו מקודם .
>
> לתורה או לארץ ישראל ארץ ישראל דרושה לנו אבל בלעדי התורה לא נתקיים
> כיהודים יש על כן לדאוג ראשית כל ליהודים ושנית לארץ ישראל בעדם מה עושים
> אנחנו הופכים את הסדר אין פוסקים לצעוק ציון ציון במקום לזעוק תורה תורה
> מה תהא עליי בלעדי התורה אנו מחוסרי עזר וישע עם התורה אנו הכבירים בעולם
> אין יו מליצה גרידאז אמת היא שדברי העולם אשרוה קנין ארץ ישראל אינו תלוי
> ברצוננו אם ה' לא יבנה בית שוא עמלו בוניו בו אבל להפיץ תורה ברבים
> בידינו הוא בנו תלוי הדבר והבא לטהר מסייעין אותו ישוב ארץ ישראל מצוה
> היא אבל הושבת קיוצות של מומרים להכעיסן עבירה גדולה היא ולא מצוה אין זה
> בנין אלא חורבן הארץ לית אינון נטורי קרתא אלא חרובי קרתא קשה ומסוכן
> חורבן זה מכל חורבנות שהמיטו הגויים על ארץ ישראל החודבמת הראשונים היו
> מכפרים על כלל ישראל

Is my understanding of this idea given by Rav Wasserman zt"l correct? Or did I misinterpreted this piece (I tried to understand it according to the plain translation though).

Why would Rav Wasserman equate Eretz Yisroel with bread? Since Torah is often compared to bread. Does he say that we must make sure that we "breath" the Torah and then Eretz Yisroel?

Comment: The quote is full of mistakes, but I think you got the gist of it. Ultimately his point is that Torah/air is far more critical to survival than EY/bread.

Comment: @shmosel TY, please feel free to correct me. I tried my best. Bread is also a metaphor for Torah, so why does he equate it with Eretz Yisroel?

Comment: It's just an analogy illustrating that two things can be necessary but not of equal priority.